# Change select box font size affect option items length

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

I need a select in html to be rectangle and large in font. So I change font size of select element, but if I set it too large it affects options width and it looks terrible.

In past I used `SelectBoxIt`, but it seems abandoned and did not work at all with the latest jQuery.

How to fix it or may be someone suggest any alternative to `SelectBoxIt`, that allows same functionality?

Here is the code snippet :

```css
    .bigselect {
        font-size: 48px;
        width: 85px;
        height: 90px;
        max-width: 85px;
    }
    
    .bigelements {
        font-size: 1em;
        width: 85px;    
    }
    
    .afire
    {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <select class="bigselect">
    <optgroup class="bigelements">
    
    <option>乙</option>
    <option>丙</option>
    <option class="afire">丁</option>
    <option>戊</option>
    <option>己</option>
    <option>庚</option>
    <option>辛</option>
    <option>壬</option>
    <option>癸</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
```

And here jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3rsLdhab/

Comment: It's the `optgroup` that cause that left indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.bigselect{
   font-size: 48px;
    width: 85px;
    height: 90px;
    max-width: 85px;
          position :relative; 
    }
.bigselect  option{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  font-size:20px;
}


.afire
{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="bigselect">
                                   <optgroup class="bigelements">

<option>乙</option>
<option>丙</option>
<option class="afire">丁</option>
<option>戊</option>
<option>己</option>
<option>庚</option>
<option>辛</option>
<option>壬</option>
<option>癸</option>
</optgroup>
                                 </select>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you i update fiddle for anyone https://jsfiddle.net/8s5onkz3/

Answer (score 0):

`<optgroup>` is useless for your purposes. The first select has the `[label]` attribute: `<optgroup label="...>` without it, it's pretty much an alignment nuisance. The second select has no `<optgroup>`.

```css
.bigselect {
  font-size: 48px;
  width: 85px;
  height: 90px;
  max-width: 85px;
}

.bigelements {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 85px;
}

.afire {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="bigselect">
  <optgroup label="bigelements">
    <option>乙</option>
    <option>丙</option>
    <option class="afire">丁</option>
    <option>戊</option>
    <option>己</option>
    <option>庚</option>
    <option>辛</option>
    <option>壬</option>
    <option>癸</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<select class="bigselect">
  <option>乙</option>
  <option>丙</option>
  <option class="afire">丁</option>
  <option>戊</option>
  <option>己</option>
  <option>庚</option>
  <option>辛</option>
  <option>壬</option>
  <option>癸</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.bigselect {
    font-size: 48px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 90px;
    max-width: 185px;
    text-align:center;
}
.bigelements {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 85px;   
    
}

.afire
{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="bigselect">
                                   <optgroup class="bigelements bigselect">

<option>乙</option>
<option>丙</option>
<option class="afire">丁</option>
<option>戊</option>
<option>己</option>
<option>庚</option>
<option>辛</option>
<option>壬</option>
<option>癸</option>
</optgroup>
                                 </select>
```

Please try this above. Hope this helps you. thanks. :)

Comment: Nope, i need that width of select was exactly 85px!